# Execute command that returns the error

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I want to make a function on postgres that tries to delete a row but if something goes wrong it must return the error.

Is there a way to do this? Something like:

```
EXECUTE 'delete from myTable where myCol = myVariable;' GET ERROR INTO e;
```

Comment: May be [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529069/raising-error-in-postgresql) will help

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: but is there a way to make the exception ruturn the error by it self? For what i know i can't make it just print, like in java: println(exception.message);

Comment: If you're executing this code from Java/JDBC you should catch `java.sql.SQLException`. It will contain the error code and other details. But you should better detect possible errors _before_ you try to delete the rows. E.g. checking foreign key constraints by queries.